# Documento Nacional de Identidad en vigor del solicitante (y cuyo estado no implique su renovación por deterioro)

Tags: significado-en-contexto

¿Qué significa "cuyo estado no implique su renovación por deterioro" en el siguiente contexto? ¿Se trata del estado del Documento Nacional de Identidad? Si es así, ¿entonces qué tiene que ver el estado de deterioro del documento con la renovación del pasaporte? ¡Muchas gracias!

"[Documento Nacional de Identidad en vigor del solicitante (y cuyo estado no implique su renovación por deterioro), que será devuelto en el acto de su presentación, una vez comprobados los datos de este documento con los reflejados en la solicitud.](https://www.madrid.es/portales/munimadrid/es/Inicio/Emergencias-y-seguridad/Direcciones-y-telefonos/Pasaporte-Solicitud-y-renovacion/?vgnextfmt=default&vgnextoid=8883557585077510VgnVCM2000001f4a900aRCRD&vgnextchannel=67e1bb21278fe410VgnVCM1000000b205a0aRCRD)"

Comment: Es el deterioro del DNI, no del pasaporte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para la renovación del pasaporte exigen el DNI en perfectas condiciones. Si presentas un DNI deteriorado o en un estado que implique su renovación, no te harán el pasaporte.

Comment: Ah ~ ahora lo entiendo todo. ¡Muchísimas gracias, Danielillo!